# Clustering with nonlinear mixed effect modeling

Tags: cluster-analysis, mixed-models, nlme

I want to optimally find the clusters and assignment of each subject into the correct cohort in the nonlinear mixed effect framework. I came to know a package in R which is lcmm that calls this type of modeling a latent class mixture model. They have the clustering of the linear mixed effect model in hlme function. I am wondering if there is a package that deals with the latent class/clustering of the nonlinear mixed effect modeling? Any help is appreciated.